# MongoDb query with unique elements and greatest value

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using the legacy c++ driver to access MongoDB and I'm currently struggling to query a set of these elements

```
{
   id: 1,
   progress: 0.3456
}
```

There are thousands of duplicate entries for the same ids, but I only want a set with unique id values and the greatest progress value for each id (or the lowest, or smaller than a specific value). Can I do this inside a single query?

So every id occurs only once but with a specific attribute to the progress (example greatest progress)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to achieve this. Your pipeline would be

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "id",
            "lowest": { "$min": "$progress" },
            "greatest": { "$max": "$progress" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": { "count": 1 }
    }
]

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

In C++, you can invoke this **[aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/cpp/aggregation/)** through the "runCommand" method which takes the database name and a BSONObj containing the command and collection, plus the actual pipeline which is an array. The final argument is the response object. You can read the full documentation **[here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/classmongocxx_1_1collection.html#aa93a46c9e07878fbddeb3ca29af71fc4)**.

For example, suppose you have a `DBClientConnection` conn to a `test` database and a collection "jobs", you can run the above aggregation operation as:

```
DBClientConnection conn;
BSONObj res;

BSONArray pipeline = BSON_ARRAY( 
    BSON("$group" << 
        BSON("_id" << "$id" ) << 
        BSON("lowest" <<
            BSON("$min" << "$progress")
        )
    )
);

BSONArray pipeline = BSON_ARRAY( 
    BSON("$group" << 
        BSON("_id" << "$id" << 
             "lowest_progress" << BSON("$min" << "$progress") <<
             "greatest_progress" << BSON("$min" << "$progress") <<
             "count" << BSON("$sum" << 1)            
        ) 
    ) << 
    BSON("$match" << 
        BSON("count" << 1) 
    )
); 

conn.runCommand( "test", BSON( "aggregate" << "jobs" << "pipeline" << pipeline ), res );

cout << res.toString() << endl
```